# change local function 

Tags: c#, winforms

I have problem with my C# WinForms project. I have a function that should change the place of buttons if they touch each other. For example, if I have `btn1` at `oldloction = (4,2)` and `btn2` at `oldlocaction (2,6)`, then if I will move the buttons and they will touch `bt1 new location = (2,6)` and `bt2 new location = (4,2)`
now i did that with 2 buttons and it works.

```
locationx - means the x  location on the button and its orgenize firat place of the location feat to the first buttons[0], the second feat to locationx[1] = buttons[1].location.x;
location - works the same ass locationx but uts the y locaion. 

    private void myText_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       Point oldlocation = new Point(locationx[0], locationy[0]);
       Point oldlocation2 = new Point(locationx[1], locationy[1]);
       if (buttons[0].Location.Y == buttons[1].Location.Y)
       {
           buttons[1].Location = oldlocation;
           buttons[0].Location = oldlocation2;
       }
    }
```

When I tried to make that as a global function it doesn't work and I don't know why.

This is the code of the global function that doesn't work:

```
  private void myText_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            Point oldlocation = new Point(locationx[i], locationy[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
            {
                if (i != j)
                {
                    Point oldlocation2 = new Point(locationx[j], locationy[j]);
                    if (buttons[i].Location.Y != buttons[j].Location.Y)
                    {
                        buttons[j].Location = oldlocation2;
                        buttons[i].Location = oldlocation;
                    }
                    else if (buttons[i].Location.Y == buttons[j].Location.Y)
                    {
                        buttons[j].Location = oldlocation;
                        buttons[i].Location = oldlocation2;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? The logic in your function? Or the fact that a *global* function won't compile since C# would require that *method* to be placed within a class...

Comment: i dont know to work with calss and its not function that needs aclass. maby its the logic you have an idea to do it beter?

Comment: Uhhmmm.... huh?  Can you compile this or are you getting an error?  Add a break point in this code and verify it actually runs, if it runs post back here and we will see what we can do, I think counter is your problem you never show us where it is declared or anything, so likely it is 0 there for your for statements never run

Comment: Let me put this another way... In C#, all methods (functions), *must* go in a class... this is not C/C++. It *MUST* go in a class

Comment: i dont have erorr it compile the code///

Comment: the counter goens with the buttons if i make button the counter++

Comment: i can make metods on the form loed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the button event for when it is pressed to call the function, rather than creating your own.

Answer (score 0):

If the second function is not part of the control or form containing the buttons, it won't have a way to access the buttons array or locationx and locationy. You may need to pass these values as arguments to your function or ensure that they are provided as members of the class containing the second function. Note that generally a utility function would not take in "sender" and "MouseEventArgs" - pass only the specific data that the utility function needs to do its job.

Comment: If this was the case though, he could not compile it